# Ubuntu server doesnt find cable connection

Tags: internet, router

I am setting up my second Ubuntu server.
The first one worked and connected properly.
This one doesnt seem to find the device drivers to connect to the ethernet.
During installation it complained of not getting connection.
Both the servers are being connected via the same router. And i had a different os on this server before that connected without a problem.

The LAN cable is connected to the computer via usb3 via the following adapter: http://www.manhattan-products.com/3-port-usb-30-hub-with-gigabit-ethernet-adapter.
Maybe some driver issue due to that?

When I type ifconfig i get no ethx. Just an lo and a wlp2s0.

I have been googling this but to no avail.

I have tried starting the networking daemon with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Doesn't work.

I have also tried going by the directions here:
[server wont connect to network; cannot find device eth0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925533/server-wont-connect-to-network-cannot-find-device-eth0)
Doesn't work.

How do I get the Ubuntu server to connect to the LAN cable?
Any hint or thoughts would be appreciated.

For info, here is the content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/#

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

and here is ifconfig -a:

[image]

and here is /var/log/syslog after sudo service network restart:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface for your USB ethernet is `enx00051bd0e80e` and not eth0. This is a result of predictable network naming: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Your settings for wlp2s0 in `/etc/network/interfaces` are faulty. As well, since you are not asking to connect by wireless, but ethernet, I suggest that you remove the wireless settings altogether. I suggest that you amend the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change the file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enx00051bd0e80e
iface enx00051bd0e80e inet dhcp
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown enx00051bd0e80e && sudo ifup -v enx00051bd0e80e
```

Did you connect?

Typically, servers are set up with static IP addresses so that you can easily ssh and ftp into them. If you wish to do so, then I suggest:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enx00051bd0e80e
iface enx00051bd0e80e inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Of course, select an address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch, or access point. Substitute your details, IP addresses, DNS servers, etc., here.

Get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown enx00051bd0e80e && sudo ifup -v enx00051bd0e80e
```

Did you get the requested address?

```
ifconfig
```

Can you reach the internet?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Yes, i did connect. Thanks a lot you really made my day.