# Ubuntu 18.04 (beta) - Cannot connect to wifi / internet

Tags: internet, 18.04

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18. And since I restarted my machine, I am not able to connect to the internet.
And this seems to be a very popular issue, because I am reading and applying the whole morning different solutions given (for example, tried this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925533/server-wont-connect-to-network-cannot-find-device-eth0)), but that does not seem to do the trick for me.

My laptop is connected to the wifi network. In fact we even have 2 in the house and I am able to successfully see and connect to both of them. 
However, when I `ping  www.ubuntu.com`, I receive "unknown host" as response. 
I am able to ping to 127.0.0.1 though.
Any other application is also unable to connect.

Any help is appreciated :)

Resolved this issue by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`. And then restarted using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`. The solution to my issue was given by  Zoltán Süle, in the comments of a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04/1021885?noredirect=1#comment1659475_1021885) like that of mine.

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting). Also, what happens if you run `ping 8.8.8.8` or any other external IP address?

Comment: I am able to ping to 8.8.8.8! Sorry for the image, but I would have to manually type everything, since I do not have internet connection on my machine.

Comment: This answer was just posted a few minutes after your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021884/no-internet-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04

Comment: Have added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`. And then restarted using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`. And that worked for me!!